# Postback issue from aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, web, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to use some source that has instructions and run this app locally and keep getting this error:

> Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using  in configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events originate from the server control that originally rendered them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to register the postback or callback data for validation.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using  in configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events originate from the server control that originally rendered them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to register the postback or callback data for validation.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [ArgumentException: Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using  in configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events originate from the server control that originally rendered them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to register the postback or callback data for validation.]
>      System.Web.UI.ClientScriptManager.ValidateEvent(String uniqueId, String argument) +144
>      System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox.LoadPostData(String postDataKey, NameValueCollection postCollection) +126
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox.System.Web.UI.IPostBackDataHandler.LoadPostData(String postDataKey, NameValueCollection postCollection) +13
>      System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessPostData(NameValueCollection postData, Boolean fBeforeLoad) +303
>      System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1960
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.34237

It builds fine and I have followed the instructions per and I was just using the default username and password:

## Freelancer Template - C#

This is a C# solution for [StartBootstrap](http://startbootstrap.com/)'s [Freelancer Template](http://startbootstrap.com/templates/freelancer/).

In this version, you'll find an Admin panel to edit all the site's content.

All the content are stored as JSON in the "data/data.txt" file - **YOU DON'T NEED SQL !**

The initial Admin username and password are :

username: admin

password: admin

To change them, you'll have to edit their values in the web.config !

To get the hashed password, you'll have to go to admin/generatepassword.aspx and get the hashed value.

The "Localfilespath" key in the Web.Config should be changed to you folder's location as well as the "MyEmail" key where you'll have to put your own email.

Finally, you'll need to give permission to the "data" and "images" folder.

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Yes. I am not sure why I am receiving this error based on what I have done (as outlined in the instructions) and am asking where else I could check or what could be causing this error?

Comment: Additionally, in VS 2013, I can view all the admin pages in page inspector and it requires me to login, but if I try to view in browser for anything in admin, it does not allow. I still have to login when going through page inspector, so not sure why I cannot do so in the browser. What I am using is in the link just out of the box with the only change in the web config being the localfilepath variable.

Comment: One more thing (forgot), the link: https://github.com/RocKhalil/Freelancer-Template

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your web.config under the System.Web section.

```
<pages enableEventValidation="false"/>
```